# Windows 8 switch between metro apps

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I am developing a windows forms aplication and I need to be able to switch between running metro apps backwards and forwards (left and right). How do I do this?

Also is there a difference doing this in 8 vs 8.1?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can check this topic:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-pictures/how-calling-win8-metro-app-by-dos-command/d197570d-d136-4a16-b320-098b30e92386?msgId=d3bdd12c-683e-4bc4-a966-9fc7111aa8c0

And also this page could be helpful for your question:

http://www.itsjustwhatever.com/2012/10/28/launch-windows-8-metro-apps-from-a-desktop-shortcut-or-command-line/